# Init process at 100% CPU usage

Tags: 11.10, server, 64-bit, cpu-load, init

I have a Ubuntu x64 machine on a OpenVZ VPS account on a QuadCore processor with 1GB/2GB(burst). A few days ago I've managed to successfully update it to 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot. There's only one problem: my "init" process (PID = 1) is at 100% CPU usage, keeping one core 99.5% of the time at full throttle.

Is there any solution to stop the strange init's behavior? Can I trace what happens behind that init process to find out what makes it spike so high?

Comment: Same for me. Unfortunately after setting log-priority to info or debug there's no additional info in /var/log/syslog or messages.

Answer (score 7):

From [Bellum PLC Forum - Ubuntu 11.10 init 100% cpu usage bug](http://forum.bellum.org.uk/Thread-ubuntu-11-10-init-100-cpu-usage-bug):

> I noticed an CPU usage issue with init due to upstart, Which was eating 99% ram constantly. and i decided to find working fix.
>   This is a bug which has been confirmed by Ubuntu but below is a simple quick fix patch which should work completely for all.
>
> Firstly Open up SSH and add the following PPA
>     `add-apt-repository ppa:jammy/upstart.fix-880049`
>    Hit enter and Enter again.
>
> If It says command not found, Issue this command first
>   `apt-get install python-software-properties`
>   Then
>   `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: I've added it to your question, you can use the "edit" button to add these details in the future :)

Comment: I know this is old, but PPA does not work anymore `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:jammy/upstart.fix-880049'. 
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, because upstart makes heavy use of ptrace() for its 'expect fork' capabilities, it is really hard if not impossible to strace or attach to it w/ gdb most of the time.

However, you can turn on verbose logging.

```
initctl log-priority info
```

If you want even more stuff

```
initctl log-priority debug
```

This may at least give some clue as to what it is doing to use up all those CPU cycles.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that init requires access to /dev/console, which does not exist in an OpenVZ virtual machine.

If you have access to the physical machine, you can create the /dev/console device, by granting access to the physical device:

```
vzctl set 105 --devices c:5:1:rw --save
```

Replace 105 with the number of your virtual server. I had the same issue, and this solved the problem without having to compile a patched init.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this is a known bug in 11.10:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/880049

A patch has been submitted:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/880049/+attachment/2567049/+files/no_dev_console.patch

EDIT: Okay, the patch seems to work, but I modified it a bit.

Adding this:

```
    if (system_setup_console (CONSOLE_NONE, (! restart)) < 0)
        nih_free (nih_error_get ());
```

to `init/main.c` after:

```
    if (system_setup_console (CONSOLE_OUTPUT, (! restart)) < 0)
        nih_free (nih_error_get ());
```

works for me, insofar as the 100% cpu issue is gone, but the devs say it's not a proper fix.

Answer (score -2):

upstart fix released by James Hewitt (2011-11-24)

https://code.launchpad.net/~jammy/+archive/upstart.fix-880049

```
#add-apt-repository ppa:jammy/upstart.fix-880049
#apt-get update
#apt-get upgrade
#reboot
```

init after reboot 0.0%